# How can I resolve all SVN conflicts automatically? (Windows CLI)

Tags: svn, tree-conflict

I'm trying to automate some Subversion processes and I'm running into problems with conflicts.  When I merge two branches, sometimes I get tree conflicts and regular (text) conflicts.  I'd like to be able to resolve everything using the repository copy:

```
svn resolve . -R --accept theirs-full
```

but if there are tree conflicts, it yells at me and says I have to resolve them to the working state.

> svn: warning: Tree conflicts can only
>   be resolved to 'working' state; 'file'
>   not resolved

Is there an easy way to resolve *just* the tree conflicts to 'working' so that I can then continue to resolve the text conflicts with theirs-full?  Or maybe another way to accomplish my goal entirely?  I'm looking to do this through the Windows command line.  Thanks!

---

Subversion server is version 1.6.6

I'm using CollabNet Subversion Command-Line Client v1.6.13 (for Windows)

Comment: To summarize the other post: the trick is to use the --accept theirs-full option with the *merge*, which will resolve all the text conflicts during the merge and leave just the tree conflicts.  Then you can resolve the tree conflicts to working.

Comment: You can also use --accept theirs-full with _update_, e.g.
`svn up . -R --accept theirs-full`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subversion Merge: How do I Cleanly Re-integrate a 'Definitive' Branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850304/subversion-merge-how-do-i-cleanly-re-integrate-a-definitive-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850304/subversion-merge-how-do-i-cleanly-re-integrate-a-definitive-branch)?

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution/workaround:

```
svn st | grep "^C" | sed "s/^........//" | xargs svn resolve -R --accept=theirs-full
```

than just resolve tree conflicts to wc:

```
svn resolve -R --accept=working
```

Not very nice, just works.

Comment: `svn resolve -R --accept=working .` (note a dot at the end) works for me